# Post a photo on a Facebook Public page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to post a photo from an iOS app to a public page.

I log in the app as the Admin of the FB App and when I got the activity token through Graph API:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request2 = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                          initWithGraphPath:@"/me/accounts"
                                          parameters: @{@"access_token": item.token}
                                          HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
            [request2 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error) 
{
   NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
   NSArray* arraydata = [userData objectForKey:@"data"];
   NSDictionary *dataD = [arraydata objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *facebookID = dataD[@"id"];
   token= dataD[@"access_token"];
}
```

I get the page token that I need to post on the page, but even if in the json I see I have all the permissions, when I post the photo it returns a 200 error (additional permission required).

If I try to post on the Admin profile (not the public page), everything works.

Any idea? What I'm missing? Can anyone you please solve this issue?

Comment: _“even if in the json I see I have all the permissions”_ – and which ones would that be, “all”?

Comment: @CBroe 

Administer
Edit_profile
Create_Content
Moderate_content
Create_Ads
Basic_Admin

Directly from json result

Comment: I meant the API permissions you requested from the user during login to your app.

Comment: You need `publish_pages` to publish anything as a page.

Comment: Like @CBroe stated, you need a page access token which has `publish_pages` permissions granted for this.